# Unique item in SharePoint list

Tags: list, 2007

Can I create a unique item in a SharePoint list to prevent duplication of entries, without deploying any app to the server?

Also if it can be done through SharePoint Designer, how it can be done??

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well good news. SharePoint 2010 seems to have this feature available.

[Link showing this feature in SP 2010](http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/jennifer/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=45)

Codeplex has project that has this feature along with others.

[Codeplex Features Project](http://features.codeplex.com/)

But if you want to do it yourself, you could possibly try this link? It seems to use an event handler to check if  the item exists. Seems simple enough, although I have not tried it but I am curious if you get it to work.

[Preventing Duplicate Items](http://www.mannsoftware.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=14)

Comment: good to know that 2010, have this feature, thanks for the info brain, well try it out

Answer (score 0):

Well not really sure but, I think you can use JQuey here and check for items when added to the library.

Comment: do you have some kind of tutorial or a guide how to do it ?